# как сделать чтобы комбинации выводились в html блочно, друг под другом?

Tags: javascript

Есть код с помощью которого я вывожу 32 комбинации + и - в html.
let result = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {

```
console.log(Array(5).fill(1).map((a, b) => '+-'[+!(i & a << b)]).join(''));
result += Array(5).fill(1).map((a, b) => '+-'[+!(i & a << b)]).join('');
```

}
document.getElementById("kombo").innerHTML = result;

Но в html они показываются слитно, вот так ++---+-+--+++--+--+-++-+-+-++-++++-+-.
Подскажите, как сделать чтобы комбинации выводились блочно, друг под другом?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
result += Array(5).fill(1).map((a, b) => '+-'[+!(i & a << b)]).join('');
```

сделать

```
result += Array(5).fill(1).map((a, b) => '+-'[+!(i & a << b)]).join('') + '<br>';
```